# Django ['“” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have a usecase model, I'm trying to update the fields in the model.

I have delivery date and estimated delivery date. It seems that delivery date is not able to update alone. If I update estimated delivery along with delivery date it gets updated. otherwise it shows an error: ['“” value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.']

my model:

```
class Usecase(models.Model):
   usecase_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20)
   usecase_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   user_email = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_email')
   usecase_type = models.ForeignKey('UsecaseType', models.DO_NOTHING)
   kpi = models.ForeignKey(Kpi, models.DO_NOTHING)
   usecase_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
   estimated_date = models.DateField()
   delivery_date = models.DateField()
```

my views:

```
def edit_usecase(request, ucid):
   try:
       usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid)
       context = {"usecase_details":usecase_details[0], "usecase_types": UsecaseType.objects.all(), "usecase_kpis": Kpi.objects.all()}        

       if request.method == "POST":
           usecase_type = request.POST['usecase_type']
           kpi = request.POST['kpi']
           estimated_date = request.POST['estimated_date']
           delivery_date = request.POST['delivery_date']
           usecase_details = Usecase.objects.get(usecase_id=ucid)
           usecase_details.usecase_type_id=usecase_type
           usecase_details.kpi_id=kpi            
           usecase_details.estimated_date=estimated_date
           usecase_details.delivery_date=delivery_date
           usecase_details.save()
           
           if usecase_details:
               messages.success(request, "Usecase Data was updated successfully!")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-details', args=[ucid]))
           else:
               messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
       return render(request, 'UpdateUsecase.html', context)
   except Exception as e: 
       print(e)
       messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
```

my template:

```
                        <form action="/update-usecase/{{usecase_details.usecase_id}}" method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                
                                <div class="form-row mb-4">
                                  <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                      <label class="h6" for="project-name">Usecase Type:</label>
                                      <select name="usecase_type" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="usecase_type">
                                          {% for usecase_type in usecase_types %}
                                          <option value="{{ usecase_type.usecase_type_id }}" {% if usecase_details.usecase_type.usecase_type_id == usecase_type.usecase_type_id %}selected{% endif %}>{{ usecase_type.usecase_type_name }}</option>
                                          {% endfor %}                             
                                      </select>                          
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                      <label class="h6" for="project-name">Usecase KPI:</label>
                                      <select name="kpi" class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="kpi">
                                          {% for kpi in usecase_kpis %}
                                          <option value="{{ kpi.kpi_id }}" {% if usecase_details.kpi.kpi_id == kpi.kpi_id %}selected{% endif %}>{{ kpi.kpi_name }}</option>
                                          {% endfor %}                             
                                      </select>                          
                                  </div> 
                              </div> 
                              <div class="form-row mb-4">
                                <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                    <label class="h6" for="project-name">Estimated Delivery Date:</label>
                                    <input type="date" id="estimated_date" name="estimated_date" class="form-control"
                                            id="estimated_date" value="{{usecase_details.estimated_date}}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 mr-f">
                                  <label class="h6" for="project-name">Delivery Date:</label>
                                  <input type="date" id="delivery_date" name="delivery_date" class="form-control"
                                          id="delivery_date" value="">
                              </div>
                            </div> 

                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Changes">
                          </form>
```

Comment: I can't see estimated_date in your models. Is estimated_date a class function?

Comment: Just edited it was deleted by mistake

Comment: Can you print and see the output of estimated_date? because it seems that the value received is None or an empty string. Just need to confirm.

Comment: if I click submit without providing values for the date is shows an empty string, now I understand the error. how do I keep the previous value if I don't update the field

Comment: You need to check if the value is None. If it is none, then don't update it.

Comment: I've added an answer for your understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template change delivery_date input:

```
<input type="date" id="delivery_date" name="delivery_date" class="form-control" id="delivery_date" value="{% if usecase_details.delivery_date %}{{ usecase_details.delivery_date }}{% endif %}">
```

In your view first check if date value is provided or not:

```
def edit_usecase(request, ucid):
   try:
       usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid)
       context = {"usecase_details":usecase_details[0], "usecase_types": UsecaseType.objects.all(), "usecase_kpis": Kpi.objects.all()}        



        if request.method == "POST":
           usecase_type = request.POST['usecase_type']
           kpi = request.POST['kpi']
           estimated_date = request.POST['estimated_date']
           delivery_date = request.POST['delivery_date']
           usecase_details = Usecase.objects.get(usecase_id=ucid)
           usecase_details.usecase_type_id=usecase_type
           usecase_details.kpi_id=kpi
           if estimated_date:            
               usecase_details.estimated_date=estimated_date
           if delivery_date:
               usecase_details.delivery_date=delivery_date
           usecase_details.save()
           
           if usecase_details:
               messages.success(request, "Usecase Data was updated successfully!")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-details', args=[ucid]))
           else:
               messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
       return render(request, 'UpdateUsecase.html', context)
   except Exception as e: 
       print(e)
       messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
```

NB: Don't use **try except** in view. It's not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you can check if the value is empty or not which you can do as follows:

```
def edit_usecase(request, ucid):
   try:
       usecase_details = Usecase.objects.filter(usecase_id=ucid)
       context = {"usecase_details":usecase_details[0], "usecase_types": UsecaseType.objects.all(), "usecase_kpis": Kpi.objects.all()}        

       if request.method == "POST":
           usecase_type = request.POST['usecase_type']
           kpi = request.POST['kpi']
           estimated_date = request.POST['estimated_date'] if request.POST['estimated_date'] else None
           delivery_date = request.POST['delivery_date'] if request.POST['delivery_date'] else None
           usecase_details = Usecase.objects.get(usecase_id=ucid)
           usecase_details.usecase_type_id=usecase_type
           usecase_details.kpi_id=kpi
           if estimated_date:            
               usecase_details.estimated_date=estimated_date
           if delivery_date:
               usecase_details.delivery_date=delivery_date
           usecase_details.save()
           
           if usecase_details:
               messages.success(request, "Usecase Data was updated successfully!")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('usecase-details', args=[ucid]))
           else:
               messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
       return render(request, 'UpdateUsecase.html', context)
   except Exception as e: 
       print(e)
       messages.error(request, "Some Error was occurred!")
       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('update-usecase', args=[ucid]))
```

You can read about [Python Ternary Conditional Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator#Python)
This should fix your issue